# Why can't I require a Java library in my Clojure file?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I've gotten leiningen to find a library I have in a corporate Artifactory repository, and it seems to download it just fine, but when I open try to `require` it, running the code with `lein run` comes back with a `FileNotFoundException`.

My project file looks like this:

```
(defproject clj-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
             [com.ourgroup/library "1.0.0"]]
  :repositories [["releases" {:url "https://url-to-our-repo"
                          :username "username"
                          :password "password"}]]
  :main ^:skip-aot clj-test.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

My single code file looks like this:

```
(ns clj-test.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [library :as lib]))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "And now for something completely different..."))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `import` a class. To get the name of the class take a look inside the jar (or at the Java source code) and find the Java package and class that make up the fully qualified class name that you need to import.

I've edited this. My earlier mistake has been corrected with the comment: "You require namespaces; you import classes. Requiring a class is no good". So for Java interop you need to import classes, the same as you would be doing if you were writing a Java source file.

Comment: This is a JAR with a package named "library", and a couple of classes in that package.  Very flat.

Comment: You require namespaces; you import classes. Requiring a class is no good.

Comment: Ah hah!  That's what I was missing.  Thanks a lot.